# правильно ли я реализовал бинарный поиск?

Tags: java, инспекция-кода

```
 public int BS(int a){

    int first = 0;
    int last = q.length-1;
    int point = q.length/2;

    if (q.length != 0 && a >= q[0] && a <= q[q.length-1]){

        while (a != q[point]){

            if (q[first]==q[last]){
               return -1;
            } else if (a > q[point]){
               first = point+1;
               point = (first + last)/2;
            } else {
               last = point;
               point = (first + last)/2;
            }

        } return point;

    } else {

        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: хм точняк , спасибо

Comment: К проверяющим: я голосую за "оставить открытым" по данному вопросу, т.к. вопросы по code review не запрещены на ru.SO.

Comment: а если вот так =)

Comment: @insolor, тогда его стоит пометить соответствующей меткой и привести в соответствие с [рекомендациями для запросов ревью](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1761/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-code-review)

Answer (score 3):

Не совсем правильно и практически совершенно не оптимально.

Во-первых, вычисление среднего элемента через формулу (first + last)/2 может привести к переполнению. Если оба индекса неотрицательны, то нужно писать first+(last-first)/2.
Во-вторых, у Вас целая куча лишних условий, реально внутри цикла достаточно иметь одно условие (если не считать условие выхода из цикла).
В-третьих, алгоритм не всегда будет правильно работать. Например, когда массив пуст или когда элемент не найден (в некоторых случаях будет выдавать сообщение, а в некоторых, нет).

Я довольно подробно объяснял типичные ошибки в бинарном поиске и рекомендации по их исправлению в [первой беседе о программировании](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lE6TeYdAxy8). Там же ссылки на программы с правильными реализациями (правда, на Си).